# How to make a request SELECT on an oracle db with parameters ? C#

Tags: c#, oracle, select, parameters, request

I want do the folowing request :

```
SELECT nom_projet, version_projet, version_build FROM analyses WHERE nom_projet=:Variable1 and version_projet=:Variable2 and version_build=:Variable3";
```

I dont understand why it doesn't work because i have done the same code for a request INSERT and this one works perfectly.

Code C#

```
public Boolean VerifierVersionDejaPresnte(ParseurXML.DonneesGblobale donneGlobale)
{
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = conn;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT nom_projet, version_projet, version_build FROM  analyses WHERE nom_projet=:Variable1 and version_projet=:Variable2 and version_build=:Variable3" 
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Variable1",donneGblobale._nom));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Variable2",donneGblobale._version));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Variable3",donneGblobale._build));

OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if(reader.HasRows)
  return true;
return false;
}
```

Comment: I assume that the missing colon at `version_build=Variable3` is just a typo?

Comment: Yes sorry, i modify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `ExecuteNonQuery` while you should call `ExecuteReader`.

`ExecuteNonQuery` is used for `Insert,Update and Delete` commands.

```
OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: when the program tries to execute cmd.ExecuteReader () I have an exception, do you have any ideas ?

Comment: What is exception ?

Comment: unfortunately I'm not sure this execption is going to help us much:
external component has thrown an exception

Comment: Can u share the exception details

Comment: I'm sorry, it was my mistake I did a error in the code ... Your answer works perfectly.

Comment: Cheers Happy coding